Load all existing .JSON files into HTML page with JavaScript using fetch()
I have
/mysite/index.html

Then I have a folder /mysite/products/ with JSON files as following:
/mysite/products/1.json
/mysite/products/2.json
/mysite/products/3.json
   ...
/mysite/products/578.json

and etc...
Every JSON file looks like this:
[{"id":1,"name":"16' Tire Japan","stock":145}]
In my HTML I have a table:
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>stock</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="products"></tbody>
</table>

Then I have a file /mysite/script.html connected with my HTML.
How can I fetch all existing .JSON files one by one from my /products folder into the table tbody (id=products) using JavaScript?
Now I have one JSON file for all products and I use fetch() like this:
fetch("products.json")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
    })
  .then(function(products){
    let placeholder = document.querySelector("#products");
    let out = "";
    for(let product of products){
        out += `<tr id='tr${product.id}'>
                <td class='id'>${product.id}</td>
                <td class='name'>${product.name}</td>
                <td class='stock'>${product.stock}</td>
            </tr>`;
    }
    placeholder.innerHTML = out;
  });


Call fetch in a loop or with .map an Promise.all

How can I do it? I played around and cannot get this done...

Wrap the code in for (let i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) { fetch(\products/${i}.json`)... }`

But what if there are 1K .json files?

Then change i <= 3 to i <= 1e3.

What does 3 mean here?

3 is the number of files. It should be 578. I haven't seen the ... and the fourth line.

I tried it. It doesn't work. It uploads only the first JSON.

Why and where do you upload JSON? You have to also fix the built HTML. But I recommend a basic JavaScript tutorial instead of this question.

Can you you give me your TGRM acc?

I do it in script.js file as described in my question.

    fetch(`products/${i}.json`)
    .then(function(response){
 return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(products){
 let placeholder = document.querySelector("#products");
 let out = "";
 for(let product of products){
  out += `<tr id='tr${product.id}'>
    <td class='id'>${product.id}</td>
    <td class='name'>${product.name}</td>
    <td class='stock'>${product.stock}</td>
   </tr>
  `;
 }
        placeholder.innerHTML = out;
    });
}```

Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question and post the code there. Also add a specific question. "How can I..." are usually not specific questions. I don't know what A TGRM acc is but I'm sure, the answer is no.

First of all you need to store somewhere information about all your "/mysite/products/*.json" files.
A. You can hardcode it in your script
const filePaths = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 578; i++) {
 filePaths.push(`http://your.web.site/mysite/products/${i}.json`);
}

B. ..or you can download it remotely.
const filePaths = fetch('http://your.web.site/mysite/products/index.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())

Then you can download all your files:
A. One by One
const array_of_products = []
filePaths.forEach(item => {
fetch(item)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    array_of_products = array_of_products.concat(data)
  })
});

B. ... or you can do that simultaneously with Promise.all(array_of_fetch)
try { 
    const responses = await Promise.all(filePaths.map(url => 
fetch(url))); 
    const jsonPromises = responses.map(response => response.json()); 
    const data = await Promise.all(jsonPromises); 

    const combinedData = data.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, ...item }), {}); 
    console.log(combinedData); 
} catch (error) { console.error('Error:', error); }

Then you can do your part of code "let placeholder = ..." to populate your table
Pleaes note that many browser has only 6-12 allowed connections and it can take quite long time to download 578 files.
Good luck with your project =)

Please don't use var. There is no reason to use it, but different reasons to not use it. Why do you have a variable MAX if you don't use it? I don't think this answer answers the whole question.

@ИринаКомсомольская Why would you use var? let and const were introduced to solve the problems that var has. Of course, you can write bad code, but an answer on Stack Overflow shouldn't contain bad code for no reason.

I changed var to const/let, it does not affect the result of the program at all.  I usually use var in examples for people who study javascript, so it's often clearer for them.
  try {
    const responses = await Promise.all(filePaths.map(url => fetch(url)));
    const jsonPromises = responses.map(response => response.json());
    const data = await Promise.all(jsonPromises);

    const combinedData = data.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, ...item }), {});

    console.log(combinedData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }


Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your answer and post your code there. Why would var be clearer in examples? New beginners shouldn't even learn, that var exists. They can learn it as advanced topic to read legacy code. Your answer doesn't contain the part about the DOM modifications.

Post your answer, then we will discuss it! ;-)

maybe something like this
see also for await...of doc
async function loadProducts()
  {
  const
    urlFiles  = ArrayFrom({length:578},(_,i)=>`products/${i+1}.json`)
  , tableBody = document.querySelector('#products')
    ;
  for await (const urlFile of urlFiles)
    {
    const resp     = await fetch(`products/${i}.json`);
    const products = await resp.json();
    for(const product of products)
      {
      let row = tableBody.insertRow();
      row.id  = `tr${product.id}`;
      row.insertCell().textContent = product.id;
      row.insertCell().textContent = product.name;
      row.insertCell().textContent = product.stock;
      })
    }
  }

